# How to smooth lines in the image?

Tags: python, opencv, smoothing

Is there a way with OpenCV to smooth the edges as shown in this small black and white image?

[image]

I tried `cv2.blur` and `cv2.GaussianBlur` but that just blurs the image. I want to smooth out the lines (black lines as shown). How could I do this?

Comment: Did you try making the image more high resolution?

Comment: @xprilion I tried on a high resolution, but it just blurs the image. Is there no way to make just the edges smooth?

Comment: There could be multiple reasons why it is so currently. Could be that the bars that you are stacking are wide and thus giving the step effect (I assumed its white bars on black background). If you could reduce their width, you'd get a more smooth sloping line

Comment: @xprilion Could you suggest a way?

Comment: I'd need to know the code (atleast the most roots level) which is generating that image. Without that I can only suggest you to try to use polygons instead of bars such that their upper portion is slanting

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer if you explain where the image came from, how it *"got the jaggies"* and what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58097626/how-can-i-soften-just-the-edges-of-this-image/58107596#58107596

Answer (score 3):

Use this, I find it very effective:
`median = cv2.medianBlur(imgBinAll, 5)`

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to run GaussianBlur over the whole image, just over the parts you need. You may create your own masks, or use as a starting point something like this:

```
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur( img, (5,5), 0)
smooth = cv2.addWeighted( blur, 1.5, img, -0.5, 0)
```

Feel free to experiment with the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can find external contour of the region, then find convex hull, and plot it with antialiased line flag on new image. See fillConvexPoly method for python.