# How to convert a pixelated image to a high quality image in python?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am working on a cutting stock algorithm and working with high quality images to calculate all possible permutations of positioning objects is not a good idea. Thus is there any way to **upscale a pixelated image to high resolution image** that also **smoothens the lines, edges and curves** in **python** ?

(i.e.) Convert this image,

[image]

to this

[image]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you start with SVGs instead?

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58466190/how-to-smooth-lines-in-the-image `cv2.medianBlur` seems to smooth the edges fairly well.