# Is There a Way to Smooth Out Jagged Lines in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm currently detecting only the black areas in an image based on color values. However, although it looks like a clear straight line to the eye, when detected based on color, it turns out jagged as shown in the image below. How can I straighten this out? I've tried almost every logic I could think of, but nothing works. I would appreciate any help you can offer.

Jagged line:

[image: jagged_line]

Original:

[image: Original_Image]

Here are the things I've tried:

- Hough Transform
- Canny Edge Detection followed by Hough Transform
- Color analysis using RGB channels, HSV channels, LAB channels, and differences between each channel
- Attempting to create a new line detection algorithm

Here is the code I tried:

```
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
r_channel = img[:, :, 2] 
b_channel = img[:, :, 0] 
r_mask = cv2.inRange(r_channel, 0, 145) 
mask1 = cv2.inRange(img_gray, 0,200) 
final_mask = cv2.bitwise_and(mask1, r_mask)
```

Comment: If you [apply a little bit of gauss blurring](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html) after the detection that may be what you're looking for. Otherwise, if I were you I would post the Python code for your line detection so we can take a look at it. I suspect you might need color thresholding; it may be jagged because it's explicitly only grabbing pixels of that color, and not the fade from that color to the background.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58466190/how-to-smooth-lines-in-the-image)

Comment: @BrockBrown  Thank you for your quick response! Below is the processing code. In the original image, the black areas are walls, and I want to detect only those cleanly. I tried the blur processing you mentioned, but it didn't have much effect. It's really frustrating that it seems so simple yet I can't solve it.



img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        
r_channel = img[:, :, 2]
b_channel = img[:, :, 0]
r_mask = cv2.inRange(r_channel, 0, 145)
mask1 = cv2.inRange(img_gray, 0,200)

final_mask = cv2.bitwise_and(mask1, r_mask)

Comment: Don't put code in a comment. Please post your question so that it can be formatted for easy reading. If you do not have enough points to edit it, then either post again with everything.

Comment: Just threshold the original on black with cv2.inrange() with range between (0,0,0) and (20,20,20). Then apply 3x3 close morphology filter on the threshold.  That for me is better than your result. Adjust the threshold and morphology as desired.

Comment: You should blur the image *before* thresholding/segmentation.