# How to sort out jagged edges images

Tags: python, imagemagick

Is there a way to sort out jagged edges alpha channel images (transparent png image) from hundreds of images. Please refer the image.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FXTI.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I soften just the edges of this image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58097626/how-can-i-soften-just-the-edges-of-this-image)

Comment: I have already tried opencv but i need to sort it out, it will be of more help.